# How to simplify the derivation of the inverse cdf yielded from l'Hospital rule?

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, derivative, quantiles

I am currently dealing with a proof of Pauline Barrieu`s Paper "Assessing Financial Model Risk" (page 19).

At one point she applys the l'Hospital rule on a limit equation. We have some cumulative distribution function $F$ and its derivation $f$ as a density function given. I just can`t follow that step:

$$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{F^{-1}(\alpha)-F^{-1}(\alpha-\varepsilon)}{F^{-1}(\alpha+\varepsilon)-F^{-1}(\alpha-\varepsilon)}
\end{equation}
$$
after applying l'Hospital rule it should be
$$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1/f(\alpha-\varepsilon)}{1/f(\alpha+\varepsilon)+1/f(\alpha-\varepsilon)}
\end{equation}
$$

But why? I really don't get it.

My approach would be applying $[F^{-1}(\alpha)]^{\prime}=\frac{1}{f(F^{-1}(\alpha))}$

But from there I won't get any further. Also the fact that $F^{-1}(\alpha)=q_{\alpha}$ doesn't seem to help.

Maybe it's obvious, but I can't see it, so if there is someone who know how to deal with a such an equation, your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're quite correct.  Consider, after all, a distribution $F$ that is not supported on a neighborhood of the interval $[0,1]$.  In that case both $f(\alpha-\varepsilon)$ and $f(\alpha+\varepsilon)$ would be zero for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$, making the limit undefined.  Evaluating the original limit depends on whether $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I get that, but I don't under stand how to get from  
$
\frac{F^{-1}(\alpha)-F^{-1}(\alpha-\varepsilon)}{F^{-1}(\alpha+\varepsilon)-F^{-1}(\alpha-\varepsilon)}
$
to 
$
\frac{1/f(\alpha-\varepsilon)}{1/f(\alpha+\varepsilon)+1/f(\alpha-\varepsilon)}
$ regardless of the limit.

Comment: My point is that this is obviously wrong.  Therefore you need to return to the first expression and perform the calculation correctly.  You haven't given enough information about $F$ and $\alpha$ to allow anyone to go any further than that in terms of deriving a definite answer.

Comment: Oh okay, so this is not true in general? Guess I missinterpreted your first answer.
Actually $F$ could be any distribtution function for example standard normal or student t, but I guess that doesn't change a thing. Also we have $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $\varepsilon<\alpha$ and $VaR_{\alpha}(X)=F^{-1}(\alpha)$ if that helps anyhow...

Comment: If you simply define $f(\alpha) = \frac{d}{d\alpha}F^{-1}(\alpha)$ (and drop the reciprocals in the second expression), then everything easily works out: L'Hopital's Rule shows the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: Alright yeah you're right thanks a lot, so I don't actually need the form $1/f(\alpha+\varepsilon)$, but $1/f(F^{-1}(\alpha+\varepsilon))$ would work as well to get the limit of $1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: This is a limits problem. Since you're taking the limit with respect to $\epsilon$, you need to take the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$, treating $\alpha$ as if it were a constant (assuming $\alpha$ *is* not a function of $\epsilon$).

For the numerator, the $F^{-1}(\alpha)$, for instance, goes to $0$, since $\alpha$ is regarded as a constant.

The term $-F^{-1}(\alpha - \epsilon)$ has derivative $-(F^{-1})^{\prime}(\alpha - \epsilon) \cdot (-1) = (F^{-1})^{\prime}(\alpha - \epsilon)$, where $\prime$ denotes the derivative. Now, by [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation), we have 
$$(F^{-1})^{\prime}(\alpha - \epsilon) = \dfrac{1}{F^{\prime}(F^{-1}(\alpha-\epsilon))} = \dfrac{1}{f(F^{-1}(\alpha-\epsilon))}\text{.}$$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually ignored the fact that I have to derive with respect to $\varepsilon$ and not $\alpha$.
So it could work like that:
$$
\frac{[F^{-1}]'(\alpha)+[-F^{-1}]'(\alpha-\varepsilon)}{[F^{-1}]'(\alpha+\varepsilon)+[-F^{-1}]'(\alpha-\varepsilon)} =
\frac{0+[F^{-1}]'(\alpha-\varepsilon)}{[F^{-1}]'(\alpha+\varepsilon)+[F^{-1}]'(\alpha-\varepsilon)}=
\frac{1/f(F^{-1}(\alpha-\varepsilon))}{1/f(F^{-1}(\alpha+\varepsilon))+1/f(F^{-1}(\alpha-\varepsilon))}
$$
Which with respect to limit tends to be
$$
\frac{1/f(F^{-1}(\alpha))}{2\cdot 1/f(F^{-1}(\alpha))}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: @Quastiat Yeah, note that there are some implicit assumptions made here. Namely, that $f$ is continuous at $F^{-1}(\alpha)$, and $F^{-1}$ is continuous at $\alpha$. Otherwise, you can't bring the limit inside the functions.